# Is this method bad for using 2D coordinates as keys in std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, unordered-map

I need to store 2D coordinates as keys in a std::unordered_map.
I know that each component of a coordinate will not exceed 16bits.

Is it bad practice to merge a coordinate pair (x,y) to an uint32_t like this

```
uint32_t coordinate_id = (x << 16) | y;
```

and use the coordinate_id as the "hash" for the map?
Or should I rather use a dedicated hash function to calculate the keys?
If I don't miss anything the method provided above will not lead to any collisions.

Comment: Do you intend to use these `coordinate_id`s as key of the map, or their computation as hash function? Can you clarify with the definition of the map and an example insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach will certainly work. It will even work, if components can exceed 16 bits: hashes are allowed to collide.

The problem here is that your hash is no better that identity function for integers. Changes to point coordinates will lead to *easily predictable* changes to hash. And if point coordinates follow some law, it is easy to accidently run into correlation between that law and bucket choosing algorithm.
Imagine if `unordered_map` created 100 buckets and places items in buckets depending on two last digits of hash. And you have points with y-coordinate evenly divisible by 100. All of your ponts will go to the same bucket, defeating purpose of hash table!